# visual studio plugins for C++ environment

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, plugins

1) I'm new into C/C++ development using Visual Studio 2008 and after some searches here i didn't find any posts related to C/C++ Visual Studio plugins besides Visual Assist X?(there are a lot of posts related to C# and asp VS environments).

2) The right approach about learning how to use those tools is to learn/try them one by one?

3) Are there some built in VS features for Todo List, bugs lists, svn, documentation or are other tools recommended by the VS users community. Which are those plugins?

MANY THX

Answer (score 1):

For a Todo list you can use the built in task list. `View -> Other Windows -> Task list` as Terry said I use Anksvn. It's not a plug-in but you can use doxygen for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/index.html) to run [PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) for C/C++ projects.

Answer (score 0):

For SVN:

http://www.visualsvn.com/

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Answer (score 0):

For Mercurial:

[VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) (VS2005, VS2008, VS2010)

and now there also seems to be a [toolbar plugin](http://mercurialtoolbar.codeplex.com/) for TortoiseHG.